# Make Fake Preloader Move Slower

Tags: flash, actionscript, actionscript-2

So i have a fake preloader going... doesnt actually preload, but just does the 'action'. my issue it gets to 100% way too fast. As its not really loading anything, how do i slow this down so its takes about 3 seconds to "complete loading?"

the code is below..

```
function onEnterFrame(){
// Calcules the max width value of the line
maxWidth = _x*2;

loaded = (_root.getBytesLoaded()/_root.getBytesTotal())*100;

// Percentage to output on the percentage textbox
per = Math.round(loaded) + "%";

// Clear this movieclip for drawing
this.clear();

// Draw the white line:
this.lineStyle(1,backLineColor,100);
this.moveTo(0,0);
this.lineTo(Math.abs(Stage.width-maxWidth),0);

// Draws the black line
this.lineStyle(1,frontLineColor,100);
this.moveTo(0,0);
this.lineTo(Math.abs((Stage.width-maxWidth)*(loaded/100)),0);
```

Comment: I added code for a fake loader bar in my response which you could test. It should be pretty easy to try out.

Answer (score 1):

ok, so frankly, that is not a fake pre-loader.

They gave you a perfectly original and well-coded pre-loader at the tutorial site.

The reason it is moving fast is because the movie has already loaded. If it hasn't loaded, you will be able to see the preloader showing the amount loaded.

To see how the pre-loader will look (i.e. to simulate the loading action), when you run the movie from Flash (Windows keyboard shortcut is Ctrl+Enter), go to View>Download Settings and select a speed to simulate the download. Then Click on "Simulate Download" (or just hit Ctrl+Enter again). You will see how the movie will load on an internet connection.

P.S.: I'm surprised the  tutorial didn't have this mentioned, because when I was learning AS2 and I looked at a preloader tutorial, it had almost identical code, but also this explanation.

P.S. 2: Why not learn AS3 instead of the (almost) obsolete AS2?

Comment: the site was already made in as2 from a few years ago when i did it. i dont want to switch to as3 just want to add the preloader. i know how to simulate download to see how it works, i just wanted the animation of the preloader to go out for 3 seconds even if site is already loaded, because the site loads really fast. its just a feature i want to see.

Comment: WHY? That defies the point of a pre-loader. Anyway, you could create an animation after the pre-loader (so the preloader will end and this animation will start). The animation goes on for 3 seconds, and then you show your actual content.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it does actually react to the loading of the main movie, but (I'm guessing) by the time the loader code actually runs the movie has been loaded, which is why it goes so fast.

If you want to fake a load time, set up a timer to run every 200ms or so and stop it after 3 seconds (making it update the load state along the way).

EDIT:

This should help you set up an interval timer -- see the section titled "To do something repeatedly at intervals":

http://flash-creations.com/notes/actionscript_timersanddelays.php

(don't forget to clear the timer when you're done with it!)

Or, since you're running this code every frame you could use the document's frames per second as your time interval and do something like:

```
fps = ...

if (i * (1/fps) < 3)
{
    loaded = (i * (1/fps)) / 3 * 100;
    i++;
}
```

in the function.

EDIT:

Here's some code which uses a timer to make a progress bar grow. To run it, just create a new Flash file (ActionScript 2.0) and plop this into the actions of the first frame.

```
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// set up the properties of the load-bar
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// set the width in pixels of the load bar
// and the X and Y coordinates it should start at
var loadBarWidth = 100;
var loadBarX = 200;
var loadBarY = 100;


////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// set-up a timer to fake loading of the movie clip
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// set how often in milliseconds the timer should run
var repetitionPeriod = 100;
// set how long we want the timer to run (in milliseconds)
var timerLength = 3000; // 3000 milliseconds = 3 seconds
// varaible to hold how long we've been running
var runTime = 0;

// start the timer
var intervalHandle = setInterval(_root, "intervalCallback", repetitionPeriod);

// callback function to run every repetition period of the timer
function intervalCallback()
{
    // add the latest inverval to the total we've run
    runTime += repetitionPeriod

    // if we've run the full amount of time
    // then stop the interval timer
    if (runTime >= timerLength)
    {
        clearInterval(intervalHandle);
    }

    // update our load bar
    // Percentage to output on the percentage textbox
    //per = Math.round(loaded) + "%";

    // draw a line
    this.lineStyle(1, frontLineColor);
    this.setRGB(255,255,255);
    this.moveTo(loadBarX,loadBarY);
    this.lineTo(loadBarX + runTime/timerLength * loadBarWidth, loadBarY);
}
```

Comment: do you mine elaborating? i'm noob. i found this code in tutorials, so i am not sure how to set up a timer.

Comment: You might want to refresh, I had to update the math a couple of times as I'm not awake yet.

Comment: thanks for your help. i checked out the link and tried a few things they said and just can't seem to get it.

Comment: i also tried your code, and the preloader just freezes lol.. i'm obviously doing something wrong. lol

Comment: My code isn't complete (e.g. you'll have to initialize `i` outside of the function). Try looking at the documentation for the functions as that should help you understand what they do better. The example at the link I posted might be a good place to start, try running it on its own maybe?

Comment: ive been working on this with the time Interval thing and still no luck. :(